# merge list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

A list of arrays looks like this:

```
x = [['0', [array([22, 15])]], ['1', [array([4]), array([9])]], ['10', [array([21])]], ['11', [array([18]), array([29, 31])]], ['13', [array([10, 13])]]]
```

How can I merge it, so that it looks like this:

```
[['0', [array([22, 15])]], ['1', [array([4, 9])]], ['10', [array([21])]], ['11', [array([18, 29, 31])]], ['13', [array([10, 13])]]]
```

First I need to pad to get the same length.

I tried it with stack_padding

```
def stack_padding(l):
    return np.column_stack((itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)))

[stack_padding(i) for i in x[:][1]]
```

But it doesn't work for the whole list.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't see any difference between the `lists` you've listed above, except for a wierd change in the `'1'` of the array, fix this please

Comment: To be clear, by `array` you mean `np.ndarray`? or what?

Comment: @YoelNisanov, I think there is a difference between the two e.g. `['11', [array([18]), array([29, 31])]]` becomes `['11', [array([18, 29, 31])]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

[[idx, [reduce(np.append, arrays)]] for idx, arrays in x]
# [['0', [array([22, 15])]], ['1', [array([4, 9])]], ['10', [array([21])]], ['11', [array([18, 29, 31])]], ['13', [array([10, 13])]]]
```

The `idx` corresponds to the strings at the begining of each sublist and we *reduce* the numpy arrays by appending one another.

Comment: wow great. That was so easy and I searched so long ... thank you very much!

Comment: can you tell me how I access e.g. 22,15, please.

Comment: If you call the resultant list `new_list`, then `new_list[0][1][0]` gives you `array([22, 15])`. Then you can reach 22, 15 with further indexing with 0 and 1 e.g. `new_list[0][1][0][0]` gives you 22.